# Android - Why can't I start the choosePictureIntent?

Tags: android, android-adapter

Im trying to start the choosePictureIntent. This is done by clicking on an image in an Ap

```
@Override
public void imageClicked(int position) {

    if(data.get(position).getImgUri() != null) {

        // IGNORE THIS
        Intent intent= new Intent(context, FullScreenActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("data", data.get(position));
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } else {

        // THIS IS THE CODE
        Object[] chooseData;
        chooseData = Utils.getChoosePictureIntent(context, context.getPackageManager());
        Intent chooserIntent = (Intent) chooseData[0];
        chooserIntent.putExtra("data", data.get(position)); // data is an array of information
        chooserIntent.putExtra("outputFileUri", (Uri) chooseData[1]);
        ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICTURE_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

When I click on the image, nothing happens, but I know that the else statement gets executed. After that, if I click on the view besides the image, the whole app freezes.
There are no error messages.

Any help is appreciated.

---

The source of `getChoosePictureIntent()`:

```
public static String getUniqueFileName(String prefix, String surfix) {
    return prefix + System.currentTimeMillis() + surfix;
}

public static Object[] getChoosePictureIntent(Context context, PackageManager manager) {
    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "imagedir" + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
    final String fName = Utils.getUniqueFileName("img_purchase_", ".jpg");
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fName);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = manager;
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Filesystem.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, context.getString(R.string.picture_chooser));

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));

    return new Object[]{chooserIntent, outputFileUri};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using targetSdk >=24, then you need to add File Provider in order to replace the File Uri received from Camera App to Content Uri because API level 24 has blocked File Uri from another app for security reason.You can check out this [link](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en) for more info

Comment: Hm, I just tried my code out without the `chooserIntent.putExtra("data", data.get(position));` part and it actually works even with the outputFileUri part. I don't understand this as I put this data to another intent in another part of the code and it worked. Might it have something to do with the intent being the choosePictureIntent?

Comment: What exactly is chooseData is returning?

Comment: Oh just realized that `choosePictureIntent` was a method inserted by me! That code was from long ago and I didn't remember, wait I added it to the post.

Comment: Also just realized that my targetSdkVersion is 23. Its so annoying that I dont get a proper error message! Just "application terminated" at this point.